# nvd3 hide specific legend

Tags: javascript, charts, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3 library to draw charts. What I've to do is to display in the chart 3 different series, but I want only two of those series in the legend.
Is it possibile to show/hide specific series in the legend?

Comment: Who has an idea if there is a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple hack with CSS:

```
.nv-legendWrap .nv-series:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}
```

This will hide the 3rd item in the legend. Not ideal, but perhaps useful.